# Determine equation of tangent plane?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, plane-curves, tangent-line

Determine equation of tangent plane in points $(\frac{1}{2},1,f(\frac{1}{2},1) )$

$f(x,y)=x^{4}-x^{2}+y^{2}$

I know usually how these examples work, but I am confused with these $3$ points. I have only $2$ variables $x$ and $y$, but $3$ points. What to do with third point?

Comment: They worded the question a bit confusingly, but I think they meant something like this: $$z=x^4-x^2+y^2$$ Usually, $f(x,y)=z$, so that would be my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

The standard equation of the tangent plane on the surface of $z=f(x,y)$ in a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ where $z_0=f(x_0,y_0)$ is given by:
$$z-z_0 = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)}(x-x_0)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)}(y-y_0)$$
where I used the notation $\left.\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x_0,y_0)}$ to indicate that these partial derivatives have to be evaluated in the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

---

**Method 2**

If you rewrite the equation of the surface in the form $F(x,y,z)=0$, so as a level set of a function of three variables, then the equation of the tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ can be elegantly written as:
$$\nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0) \cdot \left( x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0 \right) = 0$$
where $\nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the gradient of $F$, evaluated at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. With the notation of above, this boils down to:
$$\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}(x-x_0)+\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}(y-y_0)+\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}(z-z_0)=0$$

---

**Answer**

Either way, you should end up with ([Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+plane+to+z%3Dx%5E4-x%5E2%2By%5E2+at+(x,y)%3D(1%2F2,1))) something that can be simplified to:

> $$z = -\frac{x}{2}+2y-\frac{15}{16}$$

Comment: Why in formula there is no f(x0,y0)?

Comment: There is, but for simplicity I wrote $z_0 = f(x_0,y_0)$ (see the beginning of my answer).

Comment: Okay. But I am getting different results with it and without it. What should I use?

Comment: Both should yield the same result; which method does not simplify to the given answer?

Comment: With f(x0,y0). i am getting -1/8 instead -15/16 ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The point is $P=(\frac 12, 1,\frac {13}{16})$. Put your equation under the form $$F(x,y,z)=x^4-x^2+y^2-z=0$$ You have to calculate the three partial derivatives (very easy)

$$\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial y}
\\\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial z}$$ and your plan has the equation
$$\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial x}(x-\frac 12)+\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial y}(y-1)+\frac{\partial F(P)}{\partial z}(z-\frac{13}{16})=0$$

Comment: Why in formula there is no f(x0,y0)?

Comment: $$f(x,y)=x^4-x^2+y^2\iff z=x^4-x^2+y^2\iff F(x,y,z)=x^4-x^2+y^2-z=0$$ and  $$P=(x_0,y_0, f(x_0,y_0))=f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a typo. What is true is $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$